# django-cors-headers settings.py django app not working even though I've added all the requirements to settings.py

Tags: python, django, rest, cors, django-cors-headers

So, I'm using django-cors-headers with Rest Framework with Django 1.11.x, and I've pretty much followed the general advice, and yet, I'm still getting `x has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header is present on the requested resource." As you can see, I've added 'corsheaders' to INSTALLED_APPS and `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` to `Middleware`, and I've set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` to true and `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` to true, too. I've even included a whitelist option, though it's my understanding that, if `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` is set to true, the whitelist isn't needed. I've also `pip3 install django-cors-headers`. What is the deal??? BTW, I've read the README on the django-cors-headers repo. I want to know why it's not working.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'books.apps.BooksConfig',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = (
    'localhost:5555' 
)
```

And my js file that's accessing from localhost:5555 is:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }});
```

Comment: Please list the headers you *are* getting.

Comment: Okay, so it's working now. I later checked the headers in Safari rather than Chrome and found I was getting a 200 there. I disabled caching in the network setting in Chrome dev tools and refreshed et voila.

Comment: I hear your pain. For devs it's annoying how aggressive browser caching can be. :)